# The layout page could not be found in nopcommerce not working in server

Tags: nopcommerce

I am using nopCommerce 3.40 and created one custom layout page `_ColumnsOneForCheckoutComplete.cshtml`
which is working fine in `localhost` but giving below error in server.

The layout page `"~/Views/Shared/_ColumnsOneForCheckoutComplete.cshtml"` could not be found at the following path: `"~/Views/Shared/_ColumnsOneForCheckoutComplete.cshtml"`.

[image]

[image: calling in view]

Is anything I am missing or need to do extra for server?

Answer (score 0):

Please Restart Application and try again.

Comment: is there any layout for nop commerce one page layout on version 4.20 of nop commerce ?